# Rename Property Refactor Not Working in Database First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional (Update 5) and Entity Framework 6 using Database first with a modal diagram.  Within the diagram screen if I select either table or column and select "Rename..." or "Refactor..." and change the name of the table or column the refactor preview shows "No changes are required," even though those entities are in heavy usage throughout the application.  Going into the generated code and attempting to do a rename refactor from there (just to cause the rest of the program to update the property names) experiences the same behavior.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and found a fix?  I know I can always do a project wide Find & Update, but would like to figure out what the issues is here.